# Why can an int? set to null have instance properties?

Tags: c#, .net, nullable

I'm curious as to why the following code works (run under the VS debugger):

```
int? x = null;
null
x.HasValue
false
```

If `x` is indeed null, what instance does `HasValue` refer to?  Is `HasValue` implemented as an extension method, or does the compiler special case this to make it magically work?

Comment: There's a really horrible special-case gotcha with nullable types. The runtime will automatically dereference their internal value when boxing them. This means that "((object)x).HasValue" will throw a NullReferenceException. That's horrible.

Comment: @KennetBelenky actually `((object)x).HasValue` won't compile, because there's no HasValue property on object.  I think you meant to say that `((object)x).ToString()` (or `.GetHashCode()` or `.Equals(something)`) will throw.

Comment: @phoog, oops I was a little bit hasty in my description. You're right, my description is syntactically invalid. The point stands, though, that the moment you cast a Nullable to an object, it's not a Nullable anymore. No other type in the .Net framework has that property.

Comment: @KennetBelenky agreed; the special handling for `Nullable<T>` is confusing, and the boxing to a null reference is awkward.  But wouldn't it be more correct to say that `((object)x).HasValue` is *semantically* invalid?  Syntactically, it's perfectly fine.

Comment: @KennetBelenky, yeah, When I set a int? to a string variable that contained null, it then contained 0 and HasValue = true! But if I set it to null keyword, HasValue = false. Strange indeed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `x` isn't a reference type. The `?` is just syntactic sugar for [`Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx), which is a `struct` (value type).

Comment: This makes the most sense.  The comparison and assignment operators would then be overloaded as well.  However, the thing that confuses me is if I look at `x` under the Watch window, it shows `null` (which should be impossible if this is indeed a value type).  Does the VS debugger special case this?

Comment: @Mike: Well, the VS debugger is a strange beast. But I think in this case it's simply using Nullable's `ToString()` method.

Comment: @Cameron, ToString() for a nullable is documented to return an emtpy string if the value is "equal" to null. If I had to bet a nickel, I'd say the debugger is boxing it, which would produce a null.

Comment: @Anthony: So it is. Possibly the debugger checks if the value (of any arbitrary expression) is null and special cases that. Hard to say exactly what's going on without the VS source ;-) Yeah, could be boxing too.

Comment: This might be the case, though `ToString()` would return a string and I don't see quotes in the Watch window.  `Nullable<T>` must have some magic meta attributes to override the debugger behavior.

Comment: @Mike: Possibly, but I don't think Nullable<T> is *that* special. The debugger has to deal with regular objects being null (and presents the word "null" to you) all the time. You wouldn't see quotes, btw (try overriding ToString() with a simple class and you'll see in the debugger what happens)

Comment: Oh it *has* to be boxing.  Because when I do have a value, I see a `T` and not the `Nullable<T>` interface.  In fact, I can't figure out how to actually dig into the `Nullable<T>` implementation with the debugger.  They used every trick in the book to make this appear exactly as a reference type.

Comment: @Cameron - Oh yea I use `ToString()` overrides all the time as debugger helpers, it's quite a handy feature.

Comment: @MikeChristensen: The comparison and assignment operators are not actually *overloaded*. Rather, the C# compiler has a special rules.  `int? x = null;` is treated as though you'd written `Nullable<int> x = default(Nullable<int>);` and `if (x != null)` is treated as if you'd written `if(x.HasValue)`. See the C# specification for details.

Answer (score 5):

`int?` is actually a structure `Nullable<int>`. Hence this, your `x` cannot be null, because it is always instance of a structure.

Answer (score 4):

Hand-waving answer: Nullable structs are magic.

Longer answer: Null is not actually what is represented by the value. When you assign null to a nullable struct, what you will see happen behind the scenes is different.

```
int? val = null; // what you wrote 
Nullable<Int32> val = new Nullable<Int32>(); // what is actually there
```

In this case, an instance of the struct is created that has the `T Value` set to a default value and the `bool HasValue` property set to false.

The only time you will actually obtain a null *reference* from a `Nullable<T>` is when it is boxed, as a `Nullable<T>` boxes directly to `T` or null, depending upon if the value is set.

Answer (score 2):

There are several meanings to `null`.

One in programming languages which present variables and memory in a pointer-based manner (which includes C#'s references though it hides some of the details) is "this doesn't point to anything".

Another is "this has no meaningful value".

With reference types, we often use the former to represent the latter. We might use `string label = null` to mean "no meaningful label. It remains though that it's still *also* a matter of what's going on in terms of what's where in memory and what's pointing to it. Still, it's pretty darn useful, what a shame we couldn't do so with `int` and `DateTime` in C#1.1

That's what `Nullable<T>` provides, a means to say "no meaningful value", but at the level below it's not `null` in the same way a `null` string is (unless boxed). It's been assigned null and is equal to null so it's logically null and null according to some other semantics, but it's not null in the "doesn't point to anything" implementation difference between reference and value types.

It's only the "doesn't point to anything" aspect of reference-type null that stops you from calling instance methods on it.

And actually, even that isn't strictly true. IL let's you call instance methods on a null reference and as long as it doesn't interact with any fields, it will work. It can't work if it needs (directly or indirectly) those fields since they don't exist on a null refernce, but it could call `null.FineWithNull()` if that method was defined as:

```
int FineWithNull()
{
  //note that we don't actually do anything relating to the state of this object.
  return 43;
}
```

With C# it was decided to disallow this, but it's not a rule for all .NET (I think F# allows it, but I'm not sure, I know unmanaged C++ allowed it and it was useful in some very rare cases).

Comment: I believe C# actually does allow this in the case where the method is an extension method of the class.  Definitely an interesting summary on null though, `+1`!

Comment: @MikeChristensen You're correct on that, though in that case what's happening is that C# is allowing the first argument to a static method call to be null - as one would expect in any language with a concept of null - and then allowing it to be called with the same syntax as instance methods.

Comment: @MikeChristensen There's an interesting irony that C# enforces it's disallowing method calls on null by using `callvirt` IL for most calls whether they're virtual or not - `callvirt` includes a null check. There are still some times when `call` is used, and one is when a valuetype has overridden a virtual method - can't be null and can't be further derived so `call` will have exactly the same semantics as `callvirt`. Now, this in itself shows that virtual vs. non-virtual isn't the only way to judge whether to `callvirt` or `call`, but it's ironic that in C# the use is almost opposite the name.

Comment: @JonHanna: I wish there had been an explicit way to declare a non-virtual method as being callable on null objects, since it would allow immutable class objects to behave as class types with usable default values (e.g. the default value of a `string` could behave more consistently like an empty string).  Such an ability would probably also imply that `Nullable<T>` shouldn't have a `struct` constraint on `T`, but since I consider that constraint a mistake anyhow, that would have been no loss.

Answer (score 1):

When using `int? x = null` then `x` is assigned a new instance of `Nullable<int>` and ist value is set to `null`.

I don't exactly know the internals but I would assume that the assignment operator itself is somewhat overloaded.

Answer (score 1):

A nullable type isn't actually `null` since it still doesn't get around the fact that value types *can't* be `null`.  It is, instead, a reference to the `Nullable<>` struct (which is also a value type and can't be `null`).

More information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Basically, you're always referring to an instance of something when you use a nullable type.  The default information returned by that reference is the stored value (or `null` if there is no stored value).

Answer (score 1):

Nullable isn't *really* a reference type, and its instance methods are one of the places where this shows up. Fundamentally, it is a struct type containing a boolean flag and a value of the type it is a nullable of. The languages special-case various operators [to be lifting, or to consider (bool?)null false in some cases] and the null literal, and the runtime special-cases boxing, but apart from that it's just a struct.

Answer (score 1):

It's a completely new type. Nullable is *not* T.

What you have is a generic class something like this:

```
public struct Nullable<T> 
{
    public bool HasValue { get { return Value != null; } }
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

I'm sure there's more to it (particularly in the getter and setter, but that's it in a nutshell.

Comment: There are also explicit operators, but this is basically it.  Jon Skeet does a pretty good job of explaining `Nullable<T>` in _C# in Depth_.

Comment: Actually, it is a generic `struct`, not a class.

Comment: --Ignore this comment, Ninja'd by Doc Brown

Comment: @DocBrown: Fixed, per your fine observation.

Comment: Well, he *is* a time-traveller.

Answer (score 0):

The nullable type (in this case: nullable int) has a property of HasValue which is boolean.  If HasValue is True, the Value property (of Type T, in this case, an int) will have a valid value.